# Inno Setup - titles my setup as "My Setup", how to change this?

Tags: inno-setup

Here is my code: As you see I have given the name of my application, but still I get the title "My Setup" when I run it

```
[Setup]
AppName=Diabetis
AppVersion=0.9
DefaultDirName={pf}\Diabetis
DefaultGroupName=Diabetis
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\Diabetis.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir="C:\Users\nwsco\source\repos\Diabetis_sqllite\"

[Dirs]
Name: {app}; Permissions: users-full   //to allow manipulating database


[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\nwsco\source\repos\Diabetis_sqllite\Diabetis\bin\Debug\Diabetis.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\Users\nwsco\source\repos\Diabetis_sqllite\Diabetis\bin\Debug\Diabetis.db"; DestDir: "{app}" 
Source: "C:\Users\nwsco\source\repos\Diabetis_sqllite\Diabetis\bin\Debug\DSettings.db"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\Users\nwsco\source\repos\Diabetis_sqllite\Diabetis\bin\Debug\Diabetis.pdb"; 

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Diabetis"; Filename: "{app}\Diabetis.exe"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "title"? Title of a window? How does that go with your answer that suggests setting `OutputBaseFilename`, which has an effect on a file name only?

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by adding:

OutputBaseFilename=Diabetis_Setup.exe

but now I have another problem, the program will display Diabetis_Setup.exe.exe, writing therefore twice the .exe.
I have tried also:

OutputBaseFilename=Diabetis_Setup

but it does not like it

Comment: `OutputBaseFilename=Diabetis_Setup` is the correct way to change filename (but not title). What does it mean *"it does not like it"*?

Comment: It means that when I use that it will show: Diabetis_Setup.exe.exe
but I have solved it by changing into DiabetisSetup, then it is displayed corrected

Comment: Please do not use your answer to ask a New Question. Instead, simply ask a new question, per SO guidelines. Thanks.